# How to bind an element to a List?

Tags: c#, list, xamarin

I want to add the elements typed by the user on a page to a ViewModel List, but can only add to a variable

```
  public class ProdutoViewModel 
  {
     public List<Produto> produtos = new List<Produto>
     {
     };
  }
```

---

```
 public Produto produto;

 public async void novoProd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        produto = new Produto()
        {
            Nome    = Convert.ToString(Name.Text),
            Volume  = double.Parse(Volume.Text),
            Preco   = double.Parse(Preco.Text),
            Taxa    = double.Parse(Taxa.Text)
        };

        ProdutoViewModel.produtos.Add(produto);//thought here it would be adding to the List, but it don't.


    }
```

Comment: try changing the List<Produto> for an ObservableCollection<Produto>

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a reference to the ViewModel before using it in your method.

```
ProdutoViewModel produtoViewModel = new ProdutoViewModel();
```

And then adding the model to it

```
produtoViewModel.produtos.Add(produto);
```